# Flask development server blocked by proxy at work

Tags: python, proxy, flask

I am trying to use the flask development server at an office with a strict proxy that blocks the default 127.0.0.1:5000 host and port.  I have tried using different hosts and ports with no success.  I have also tried setting up Flask with XAMPP on Windows via mod_wsgi with no success.  I am looking for an option to continue testing flask on my local machine with as little setup as possible as my production environment is a PaaS and does not use the same setup as my local machine.

Comment: Do you have root access? Because you could try running Flask on the 80 port.

Comment: Their apache server is on port 80